# Usage of 'never had before'

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I am going to present a funny gift to my friend. What is the best sentence which will describe the item? Is the following sentence correct?

> Be prepared to get a gift which you never had before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this:

> Be prepared to get a gift that you won't expect.

To stir up the most turmoil within the recipient, that would work. Or something like this:

> Get ready for a once-in-a-lifetime gift!

It's really up to you. The sentence that you gave doesn't convey the meaning that you're trying to get across (be ready for anything) as well as the above examples, since it simply means *be ready for a gift that you haven't had before*, which could be something like a piece of chalk, which is not necessarily funny, but simply something they have never received. My examples do not convey the exact meaning (be ready for a funny gift) because I think that you'd be giving away too much information. A gift should be a surprise!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the same sentence, you just need to change the form of *have* to make it read *Be prepared to get a gift which **you’ve never had** before.* But a native speaker of British English would be more likely to say something like *I’ve got a surprise for you. It’s a present which I bet you’ve never beeen given before.*

Comment: +1, but what this page needs is a concise explanation of the difference between "you had" and "you have had" - one which I am unable to give.

Comment: @slim: ‘You had’ is past tense, which locates an event at a specific time in the past. ‘You have had’ is a perfect construction and relates a past event to the time of speaking.

Comment: Neat. I suggest bunging that in the answer, along with what adding "never" means. "You never had" isn't wrong; it's just different to "You've never had".

Answer (score 1):

A *never-before* gift. The collocation 'never before' is quite popular and widely used for dramatic effect.

Answer (score 0):

> Be prepared to receive a gift, the likes of which you’ve never had before!